# Preferrable version for phone-gap between 1.8 and 2.0

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I wanted to know which latest version of phone-gap should i use(with IOS 5.0 and android 2.2) which is dependable and bug-free right now. The phone-gap version should have the built-in capability of taking the back-up of data stored in /Cache(as that is where phonegap tries to find db by default) ie. localstorage whenever IOS deletes files from Cache due to low memory.

Any suggestions are most welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

phonegap 2.1.0 is the latest, and so far i have no problems with it , im using ot both for android and ios :)

[Download](http://phonegap.com/download)